# How to choose snooze time for calendar event notification?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, calendar, notifications, alarm

Maybe I took this for granted in my Windows Mobile years - but I'm having an issue with my new Galaxy S (Fascinate on Verizon). When a reminder pops up for a calendar event, I only see an option to "Snooze All" or "Dismiss". Can I not pick a snooze time? It appears that the default snooze time is 5 minutes. On Windows Mobile, when a reminder pops up, I can choose to snooze 1, 5, 15, 30, 60, 120 minutes etc. I used this constantly and would really hate to lose it. I'm sure there are third party apps that can do this, but does anyone know if there's a way to do this with the stock calendar? Thanks!

Comment: Your original title (How to choose snooze time when alarm goes off?) sounds to me like you are asking about the Alarm Clock app.  I edited it to make it more clear that you want to snooze your calendar event notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a great app called Calendar Snooze that does exactly what I was looking for. You can set custom snooze times, set how often the reminders repeat if you don't snooze them, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an alarm using the (stock) Clock app, under the "Notification" you can set "Snooze" options: the duration of a snooze and the frequency of the snooze.
I don't think you can choose the snooze duration when you click snooze at the actual alarm time though.

Comment: I think he's referring to snoozing the Calendar App notifications, not the Alarm Clock.